# Redirect the Windows console output of a Python script without raising UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: powershell, python, pipe, character-encoding, windows-terminal

I have a Python script called `scratch_1.py` which can be simplified for the sake of the question to:

```python
s = "∞"

print(s)
```

If I run the script in the Windows console, I get the expected output:

```bash
python scratch_1.py
```

Output:

```
∞
```

However, if I try to redirect the output of the Windows console to a file, an error is raised:

```bash
python scratch_1.py > temp.txt
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Wok\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2022.2\scratches\scratch_1.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(s)
  File "C:\Users\Wok\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u221e' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

I have come up with [a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console/74509356#74509356).

However, I would prefer a solution which **does not require to modify the Python script**.

---

I have though of using `chcp 65001`.

This has lead to the observations shown below, but this did not fix the Python error.

---

```bash
chcp
echo ∞
```

Output:

```
850
∞
```

---

```bash
chcp
echo ∞ > temp.txt
type temp.txt
```

Output:

```
850
8
```

---

```bash
chcp 65001
echo ∞ > temp.txt
type temp.txt
```

Output:

```
65001
∞
```

---

```bash
chcp 65001
python scratch_1.py > temp.txt
```

Output:

```
65001
UnicodeEncodeError (same as before)
```

---

Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/q/1070933/57189 & https://superuser.com/q/1056614/57189