# Control encoding of batch-created file

Tags: batch, utf-8

I wanted to automate the creation of a directory tree file in Windows 10.

In PowerShell, I executed the following commands:

```
cd  C:\TreeTest
tree /f > .\TreeStructure.txt
```

The output was a pretty UTF-8 file:

[image: Pretty UTF-8 tree structure test]

Now I wanted to do the same thing in a batch file:

```
@echo off
cd  C:\TreeTest
tree /f > .\TreeStructure.txt
```

But the output from the batch file execution had the encoding screwed up:

[image: Bad encoding tree structure test]

Why is the encoding of the PowerShell output different from the output of the batch file?

I know that I can get an ASCII output by adding /a to the tree command, but I would prefer the pretty UTF-8 output to be saved to my tree file.

I tried changing the codepage by adding "chcp 65001" to my batch file, but it didn't change the file output.

Comment: [Command Prompt “tree” shows Unicode in console but outputs to file in ASCII](https://superuser.com/q/1056614/241386), [Saving 'tree /f /a" results to a textfile with unicode support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/138576/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LotPing's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1408345/376602) is right. Just for detailed description:

The `>` redirection operator (*send specified stream to a file*):

- in *Windows PowerShell*, default encoding of an output file is *UCS-2 LE BOM*:

> When you are writing to files, the redirection operators use *`Unicode`*
> encoding. If the file has a different encoding, the output might not
> be formatted correctly. To redirect content to non-Unicode files, use
> the `Out-File` cmdlet with its `Encoding` parameter.<sup>1</sup>
>
> <sup><sup>1</sup> Copied and pasted from `Get-Help about_Redirection -ShowWindow` as there is a mistake in the [online documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-5.1#notes)</sup>

- in *PowerShell Core*: Beginning in [PowerShell 6](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6#notes), default encoding changed to *BOM-less UTF-8* when writing to files:

> When you are writing to files, the redirection operators use
> `UTF8NoBOM` encoding.

- in [Windows command prompt (`cmd.exe`)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):
- `cmd.exe` (default): the output of internal commands to a pipe or file is `OEM`,
- `cmd.exe /A`: causes the output of internal commands to a pipe or file to be *`ANSI`*, and
- `cmd.exe /U`: causes the output of internal commands to a pipe or file to be *Unicode* i.e. `UCS-2 LE` (no `BOM`):

> The `CMD` Shell can redirect `OEM`/`ANSI`/Unicode
> (`UCS-2 le`) but not `UTF-8`.
>  This can be selected by launching
> `CMD` or `CMD /A` or `CMD /U`.

However, output of the *pretty old-fashioned* utility `tree.com` isn't ready to be converted to Unicode. Therefore, straight `start "" cmd /U /C "tree>tree_U.txt"` still produces ([mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)) garbled (`OEM` encoded file interpreted as `ANSI`). The following `cmd` commands should do the trick:

```
tree>"%temp%\auxTree.txt"
start "" cmd /U /C "type "%temp%\auxTree.txt">tree_Unicode.txt"
del "%temp%\auxTree.txt"
```

BTW, here are those *pretty* characters and their codes (garbled in `ANSI`):

```
Char Unicode  OEM  ANSI  UTF-8     Character_description
 ─   U+2500   196  n/a   0xE29480  Box Drawings Light Horizontal
 │   U+2502   179  n/a   0xE29482  Box Drawings Light Vertical
 └   U+2514   192  n/a   0xE29494  Box Drawings Light Up And Right
 ├   U+251C   195  n/a   0xE2949C  Box Drawings Light Vertical And Right
```

And the [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case mechanism (example in Python for its common intelligibility):

```
' ─ │ └ ├ '.encode('cp437').decode('cp1252')
```

> ```
> ' Ä ³ À Ã '
> ```

Comment: Note: when redirecting `cmd.exe /A /C "command > abc"` output, make sure that redirection operator `>` inside quotes, otherwise redirection will use parent shell encoding.

Answer (score 5):

You are wrong in assuming your editor `Notepad++` reads the file created in PowerShell as UTF8.

It is `UTF16-LE`/`UCS-2 LE-BOM` with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) `0xFF 0xFE`

The tree file created in cmd.exe is encoded in the actice codepage, see output of `chcp`
and change the encoding in `Notepad++` accordingly.

```
> chcp
Aktive Codepage: 850.
```

Change Encoding (in my German locale Notepad++):

[image]